# Which element does each Miraculous correspond to?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

There are three tiers in the Miraculous box.

[image]

The Ladybug and the Cat correspond to Yin and Yang respectively. The bottom twelve correspond to the Chinese Zodiac. The middle five (Peacock, Bee, Butterfly, Fox, Turtle) correspond to the five classical Chinese elements. However, the colors in the box do not match the traditional colors of the elements, nor does this seem to be explained on the show.

Which elements correspond to which of the five Miraculouses?

Comment: I have only an approximate knowledge of [many things, including] _Miraculous_ but ... doesn't the bottom tier in the image contain ***eight*** items rather than ***twelve***?

Comment: Some are hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best theory I've heard is that

- Fox = Fire
- Butterfly = Wood
- Peacock = Water
- Turtle = Metal
- Bee = Earth

This is actually the order of the elements when placed in a circle, and the order the Miraculous are arranged in the box.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This sounds like a reasonable theory; your answer would be made stronger if you linked to a source that showed the order of the elements for those who are unfamiliar with it.  For example: https://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/chinese-zodiac/china-five-elements-philosophy.htm